# How to convert string 'mm-yyyy' column to timestamp in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string-to-datetime

I want to convert string column of format 'mm-yyyy' to timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following logic. As you have only Month and Year value in your string, I have added the static date 01 to each date to generate the DATETIME value.

```
select 
CAST(
    CONCAT(right('06-2019',4) , '-', left('06-2019', 2),'-01') AS DATETIME
);
```

Comment: Throws error `Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function CAST` when executed. Can you please correct it.

Comment: Updated. There were issue basically related to spacing between lines.